# React-Native Error After Installing ZSH

Tags: bash, reactjs, react-native, zsh, jsx

Every time i run my react-native app (run-android), i get this error.When i was working with bash i didn't have any problems. After i installed zsh, that error started to happen. I checked all the SDKs but couldn't find the solution.The image for the error is down below.
Thanks for helping already.

The error:
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: is ANDROID_HOME path variable in your path ? check by doing : echo $ANDROID_HOME

Comment: I checked, it is: /home/hakan/Android/Sdk

Answer (score 2):

You must set variable path to zshrc, and in my zsh i already set the path with :

1. Open your terminal
2. run this command : `nano ~/.zshrc`
3. Set your path variable like this :

   `//your java home path 
    JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121"
    export JAVA_HOME
    //your android home path
    export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-SDK/Android/Sdk
    //your path
    export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/opt/android-
    SDK/Android/Sdk/tools:/op$`
4. Save .zshrc file using : `CTRL+X`

I hope this answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The react-native script by default reads your .bashrc for path variable,but since you installed zsh,the path variable is in .zshrc